# Excell Restriction on cell

Tags: excel-formula

Please what is the formula to limit the number input in excel sheet.
e.g my cell A1 suppose to have the highest value of 10, to avoid putting more than 10 in that cell.

Comment: You have to apply data validation - not a formula

Comment: Please how do I apply the data validation

Comment: google for excel data validation - you will find tons of tutorials.

Comment: Thanks a lot I've discovered it and a new way handle the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "options from list" which will only allow the values from the list to be set as value of the cell or you can put "if" function to accept or reject the input values or you can use "drop down" to do the same